# Default php gettext variable interpolation settings

Tags: php, translation, interpolation, gettext

$s, ${s} or {{s}} won't work for me.

What are default settings for variable interpolation in php gettext?

```
msgid "w_clients_details_vatid"
msgstr "Cannot obtain VAT identification number for client: {{s}}"
```

I call it like: _("w_clients_details_vatid"); Text displays as it is supposed to. But no interpolation occurs.

Comment: Try using `{$s}` instead.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Remember to use double quotes.

Comment: msgid "w_clients_details_vatid"
msgstr "Cannot obtain VAT identification number for client: {{s}}"

I call it like: _("w_clients_details_vatid");
Text displays as it is supposed to. But no interpolation occurs.

Comment: Maybe this'll be useful for you: http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Interpolation-I.html

Comment: Well this doesn't clarify the method for interpolating variables.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but is it something like this?

```
$s = "Some Text";
echo "\$s contains: {$s}";
```

**Result:**

> $s contains: Some Text

Please post some code to clearify the problem.

Comment: For this putting it in curly braces isn't needed though.

Comment: @RichardA No, but I think it's better to be consistent with the braces and I think it's more readable too.